# Viewing ELMAH logs through the web interface on a Live application

Tags: elmah, error-logging, elmah.mvc, exception-logging

I have included elmah.mvc into an Asp.Net MVC application for logging exceptions and custom error logs. It is working fully as intended and I can view the logs within my ELMAH_Error table using a SQL Server, and as well from the web interface through local host URL(http://localhost:20086/elmah).

My question is: How, if possible, can I view my logs through the web interface on a live site and not "http://localhost:20086/elmah". I want to be able to view the Logging information when necessary from any computer. I have implemented Roles and Authentication, so I should be able to go to the correct URL, login with the appropriate credentials, then view the logs.... right? 
Is this possible??

Answer (score 3):

No problem. You can use ASP.NET authentication to secure your logs. Basically you want something like this:

```
<location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD"
                 path="elmah.axd"
                 type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="admin" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ELMAH"
                 verb="POST,GET,HEAD"
                 path="elmah.axd"
                 type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"
                 preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

There's some more details in this [ELMAH Tutorial](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/#securing-the-error-log).

It looks like you're using the Elmah.MVC package. With this package you have another option:

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="admin" />
```

Comment: Hi, ThomasArdal
I know about the authorization/roles and I have already implemented this.  What I am trying to figure out is how to view the ELMAH web interface to view the logs. I can only do it from local host. Can I do this through my live site, because http://tc-solutions.dk/elmah brings me a 404 error

Comment: Did you set the allowRemoteAccess attribute to true? If not, look in the tutorial.

Comment: Yes, It is working fine as intended. I miss understood something in the tutorial, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you misunderstand. I will make sure to make it more clear.

Comment: Shouldn't this be the accepted answer?

Comment: I would appreciate that at least :)